# How to register Task Queues from backend modules of Google App Engine application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-engine-modules

I am working on a Google App Engine(1.9.34) application with multiple modules.

Here I am able to register queues (using queue.xml) from default module. But I want to register queues from backend module.

I have placed `queue.xml` in `BackendModule/war/WEB-INF/queue.xml` with required configurations like:

```
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>myBackendQueue</name>
        <rate>1/m</rate>
        <bucket-size>1</bucket-size>
        <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
        <mode>push</mode>
        <target>mycloudbackend</target>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

But this queue is not visible in cloud admin console `Task Queues` menu.

Am I missing any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

this is a know problem with multiple versions of GAE, this page gives suggestions on possible fixes. [Task queues don't work with multiple modules on development server](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35896906)